# Things to note with Microsoft Web Platform?

Tags: windows-server-2003, microsoft-web-platform

Has any one used [Microsoft Web Platform](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)? What is the installation like? Does it require IIS to go down or the server restarted? How smooth is the update process? Any gotchas that I should be worried about putting this on a production server? What were thinking is running PHP for WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I recall if your just installing PHP and wordpress components it does not require a restart, however it may require a restart of IIS.
If you are concerned how this will affect your production server I would suggest you test this in a lab environment before hand, its always worth doing this so you are sure of what will happen, and how to do it. Alternatively you could look at installing PHP and wordpress manually.

Answer (score 1):

It looks more like it is intended for a developer machine. If I were you and wanted to install Wordpress, I'd install PHP for IIS, which is a very simple install.

I'd be concerned about Microsoft Web Platform overwriting your current IIS configuration. At the very least, take a complete backup before installing it.